# How to stop remote script in Fabric

Tags: python, shell, unix, deployment, fabric

I have a deploy script in Fabric which runs remote command:

`sudo('chroot {} /srv/bin/update.sh'.format(CHROOT_DIR))`

There are some cases when I want to stop execution of update.sh - when I do ctrl + c in terminal it only exit from my fabric script - remote script is still working.

Is there any way to stop execution of remote command in fabric?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is supposed to pass on your ^C to the remote session:

```
from fabric.api import settings

with settings(remote_interrupt=True):
    sudo(...)
```

Comment: @SerafimSuhenky , this was written quite some time ago, feel free to edit with more recent information